# Buying cheap flights in Jordan

Tags: air-travel, budget, tickets, middle-east, jordan

It is known that throughout Southeast Asia, tickets are fairly cheap (so, when you buy them on location, from €30/$30 from one Southeast Asian country to another).

Does this also count for the countries in Middle-Asia? For example, Jordan?

Comment: Are talking about flights within Jordan or from Jordan to other/nearby countries?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee From Jordan to nearby countries.

Comment: can you tell the destination(s)?

Comment: Hmm... let's say India, Thailand, Vietnam. But also Egypt, Saudi Arabia, Oman.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking for budget flights from Jordan?

You can find which budget airlines fly from Jordan here: http://www.airninja.com/

There don't appear to be any budget airlines inside Jordan.

Comment: The site appears to be a common ticket-search engine like http://www.skyscanner.com. I like to know whether getting tickets locally is cheaper. (so when I search for cheap tickets at the airport in Amman)

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not get that from your question. Note, though that airninja is not a ticket-search engine. It lists which budget airlines fly from where to where. Typically, you won't be able to find flights on budget airlines with a ticket search engine.

Comment: I don't know about all budget airlines, but the few I found with airninja, I also found with skyscanner. Not a very thorough test though...

Comment: Sadly, airninja is no longer what it used to be. It used to be a purely budget search engine, but is not a regular flight search engine. :(